# Select data from one view and use that to select from another view

Tags: sql, select, view

I have 2 views with data and they are related via an ID column.

I need to select from view A some ID's based on another ID. This will often result in a set of ID's.

Then I need to use this set of ID's to select rows from another view.

I could do this with 2 queries, but I'd like to do it in a single query.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM ViewA a
        INNER JOIN ViewB b
            ON a.CommonID = b.CommonID
    WHERE a.OtherID = xxx
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the solution.. however I get an error

ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: also I just saw that the commonID have different datatypes.. one is an integer and the other is a varchar. 

How can I compare them? I've tried to CAST (b.commonid AS integer), but get the above-mentioned error

Comment: Ignore the above comments.. I solved the problem by convertin the database field to integers to avoid casting them to integers. Solved it!

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table1
where id in (
    select some_id from table2 where id in (
        select some_other_id from table3 where some_condition));
```